# websphere EJSLocalWrapper

Tags: websphere, ejb

In my IBM websphere EJB app, there is a facade class. There also is a class like this:  (as below)

```
EJSLocalStatelessFacade_f89c8f6d extends EJSLocalWrapper.
```

This is a websphere container generated class. From first glance, it is not immediately clear what this is doing? I recently moved from weblogic to websphere and in weblogic, there is no such thing as localwrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That generated class is the local proxy class.  It performs pre/post-invoke handling (security, transaction, interceptors, allocates bean instance, etc.), and then invokes the underlying bean instance.  The same effect could be accomplished using Proxy.newInstance, but the generated wrapper allows for greater efficiency.

Comment: Why in weblogic, there is no local proxy class? Or is there?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Weblogic, but the EJB programming model effectively requires a local proxy class (either Proxy.newInstance or like newer versions of WAS, a concrete class that is created in memory only).